# How to use thymeleaf to search and bring back data

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

[Thymeleaf] How can I bring data from search to controller

I am making a search and bring back the result back, but I use `th:value`, it is not working and how to make a search with two criteria.

```
<form th:action="@{/home/checkorcancelapplication}" method="post" autocomplete="off"><li>Application No. :
<input type="text" th:value="${search}" name="search" ></li>
    
<li>Phone Number : 
<input type="text" th:value="${search}  name="search" ></li>
<button type="submit" value="Search" class="searchbutton" onclick="printmsg()">Search</button>
</form>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home/checkapplication")
    public String maintainUserEnquiry(ModelMap model, @Param("search") String keyword) throws Exception {
        if(keyword != null) {
            
            Application inclass = CheckApplicationService.findByApplicationNo(keyword);
            model.addAttribute("inclass", inclass);
        }else {
            return "home/checkapplication";
        }
    return "home/checkapplication";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you're trying to use the same variable `search` for both the application number and the phone number, which is causing the issue.

To search by both application number and phone number you need to have separate parameters for each in your form and your controller method.

Change your form to have separate fields for the application number and phone number. Use different names for each to differentiate them.

```html
<form th:action="@{/home/checkorcancelapplication}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <li>Application No.:
        <input type="text" th:name="applicationNo" name="applicationNo" ></li>
    <li>Phone Number:
        <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" ></li>
    <button type="submit" value="Search" class="searchbutton">Search</button>
</form>
```

I removed `th:value` since we typically use it to populate input fields with existing data, and you're trying to capture new data from the user. Also, `th:name` is not valid; you should use just `name` to identify form fields unless you're setting it dynamically.

Now, your controller method should accept two parameters: one for the application number and another for the phone number. You can use `@RequestParam` to capture these from the form submission.

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/home/checkorcancelapplication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String maintainUserEnquiry(ModelMap model, 
                                  @RequestParam("applicationNo") String applicationNo,
                                  @RequestParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber) throws Exception {
    // Logic to search by applicationNo and phoneNumber
    // This is an example
    if(applicationNo != null && phoneNumber != null) {
        // You should have a search method in the service 
        Application inclass = CheckApplicationService.findByApplicationNoAndPhoneNumber(applicationNo, phoneNumber);
        model.addAttribute("inclass", inclass);
    } else {
        return "home/checkapplication";
    }
    return "home/checkapplication";
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to require both an application number and a phone number for the search. If you want to make either optional, you'll need to adjust your logic to handle cases where one or the other (or both) are provided.

Hope it will help. Thanks